# Change the colour of row in kendo grid based on date column value in angular

Tags: angular

[image]I have a kendo grid like this

```
<kendo-grid
  [data]="gridData"
  [selectable]="false"
  [kendoGridSelectBy]="'Id'"
  [selectedKeys]="selectedIds"
  [pageable]="{ pageSizes: gridPageSizes }"
  [pageSize]="state.take"
  [skip]="state.skip"
  [scrollable]="'none'"
  [groupable]="false"
  [group]="state.group"
  (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
  [filterable]="false"
  [filter]="state?.filter"
  [sortable]="true"
  [sort]="state?.sort"
  [rowClass]="rowCallBack"
>
<kendo-grid-column
    field="invoiceNumber"
    title="Invoice Number"
  >
  </kendo-grid-column>
 <kendo-grid-column
    title="PO"
  >
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
      {{dataItem.PO}}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>

 <kendo-grid-column
    field="StatusChangedDate"
    title="StatusChangedDate"
    filter="date"
    format="{0:d}"
  >
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <time>{{ dataItem.StatusChangedDate | l10nDate: language:'short' }}</time>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

How can I colour whole row (or the record) in the kendogrid if the StatusChangedDate is 1 week older and show an alert image/symbol on the invoice number column along with the invoice number

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please say what format is `StatusChangedDate` in? Or do you know already how to check if 1 week has elapsed since a certain `StatusChangedDate`?

Comment: Hi Michael
The date format is as such 2018-01-01T08:00:00.No I dint know the elapsed time .Pleaes let me know how to solve this scenario

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A callback function is bound to `[rowClass]` property already. We can use it to check if one week has elapsed since `StatusChangedDate` date and set the custom background color.

Also notice the `encapsulation` option in component decorator. [`ViewEncapsulation.None`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#None) instructs Angular to use global CSS without any encapsulation. Finally in the CSS `highlight` selector is added to the Kendo grid CSS selector `.k-grid tr` to set the background color.

The following should do it

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { RowClassArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

import { sampleData } from './data';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [
      `
      .k-grid tr.highlight {
        background-color: #ff6666;
      }
      `
    ],
    template: 
      `
      <kendo-grid id="grid"
        [data]="gridData" 
        [resizable]="true"
        [rowClass]="rowCallBack"
        [selectable]="false"
        [kendoGridSelectBy]="'Id'"
        [pageable]="{ pageSizes: gridPageSizes }"
        [pageSize]="20"
        [skip]="true"
        [scrollable]="'none'"
        [groupable]="false"
        [filterable]="false"
        [sortable]="true">

        <kendo-grid-column field="invoiceNumber" title="Invoice" width="40">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column title="PO" width="80">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
            {{dataItem.PO}}
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="StatusChangedDate"
          title="StatusChangedDate"
          filter="date"
          format="{0:d}"
          width="80">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <time>{{ dataItem.StatusChangedDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</time>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>

      </kendo-grid>
      `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public gridData: any[] = sampleData;

  public rowCallBack(context: RowClassArgs) {
    const utcOld = Date.parse(context.dataItem.StatusChangedDate);
    const utcNow = new Date().getTime();
    if ((Math.abs(utcNow - utcOld)) > 604800000) {  // 604800000 = 1 week in microseconds
      return { highlight: true };
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ui-grid-uccmyz)

Comment: The statuschangeddate that is returned from backend is more like 2018-01-01T08:00:00.Can you update the data as such and let me know.Because this line doesnt work for me
 const utcOld = Date.UTC(dateOld.getFullYear(), dateOld.getMonth(), dateOld.getDate());

Comment: In that case use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) instead of `Date.UTC()`. I've updated the code. Take a look.

Comment: dataOld.getFullYear doesnt work.can you please update the stackblitz sample with the date format i mentioned in the 'statuschangeddate'

"StatusChangedDate": new Date('02/20/2020'),

this is the one I was refering to.Can you change the date to something in the format
"StatusChangedDate": '2018-01-01T08:00:00',

Comment: Please look at my updated code here in Stackoverflow. That should work for you. Replace the line `Date.UTC(dateOld.getFullYear(), dateOld.getMonth(), dateOld.getDate());` with `Date.parse(context.dataItem.StatusChangedDate);`.

Comment: Okay I've updated the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ui-grid-uccmyz

Comment: thank you.One more thing to it, How can I show an exclamatory on one of the columns based on this condition.Have updated the main question with the image of the exclamatory that has to be appended to the column value in the grid

Comment: That is a separate question because you need to append an image based on a condition. This question's purpose to change row background based on a condition is complete. I'd say it's better to start a new question and show something that you've tried so that other people may also look at the problem.

Comment: @Nihali: And if it solved your issue, it'd be great if you could accept and upvote the answer.